# How to find all classes that implements a generic abstract class using reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have a `c#` class that looks like this

```
public abstract class Listener<T> where T : Event
{
    public abstract void Handle(T _event);
}
```

I extend this class something like this

```
public class SendWelcomeEmail : Listener<UserWasCreated>
{
    public override void Handle(UserWasCreated _event)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

I need to use reflection to find all classes that extend the `Listener<>` base class.

I tried the following

```
var listeners = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                         .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
                         .Where(x => x.IsClass && !x.IsInterface)
                         .Where(listener => !listener.IsAbstract && listener.IsGenericType && listener.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Listener<>))
                         .ToList();
```

But that does not return anything. This condition returns false all the time `listener.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Listener<>)`

How can I correctly find all the classes that extend the `Listener<>` base class?

Comment: Your query doesn't make any sense. You say you're looking for types whose *base types* include `Listener<Something>` but your query looks for types that **are** `Listener<Something>`.  If you're looking for base types then somewhere in the query you're going to have to, you know, **mention base types**!

Comment: You need to take a step back and solve an easier problem. Suppose I give you a `Type` object. Can you list all of its base types? If you can't do that, then you can't solve the harder problem.  **When you are stuck, find a simpler problem that relates to your problem and solve it.**

Comment: Your query is weird in other ways too.  Like, you say "where the type is a class and not an interface".  That's like saying "I'd like an animal that is a dog and not an octopus" -- by the time you know it is a dog, you don't have to test it for octopusness. This code looks like you're throwing stuff at the compiler and hoping something sticks. Start over, and write the code carefully and logically.

Comment: Also, suppose we have class `Foo` which extends  `SendWelcomeEmail`. Does it extend `Listener<>` ?  Sure it does. But do you want to list it? or do you want only the types that *directly* extend `Listener<>`?

Comment: @MikeA If you want just to know all classes that inherit from your class, you could place cursor somewhere in your class name in Visual Studio and find all references (hit Ctrl+F12)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Start by building up the infrastructure you need: put more tools in your toolbox, and then use those tools.

You want to list all the base types of a type, so list all the base types of a type:

```
static class Extensions
{
public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypes(this Type type)
{
    Type t = type;
    while (true)
    {
        t = t.BaseType;
        if (t == null) break;
        yield return t;
    }
}
}
```

Now we have a useful tool in our toolbox.

We have a type in hand. We wish to know if something is true of any of its base types.  Therefore we should be using `Any`:

```
static bool AnyBaseType(this Type type, Func<Type, bool> predicate) =>
  type.BaseTypes().Any(predicate);
```

Now we have another useful tool.

We want to know if a particular type is a particular generic:

```
static bool IsParticularGeneric(this Type type, Type generic) =>
  type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == generic;
```

We want to know if a particular type is a listener:

```
static bool IsListener(Type type) =>
  type.IsParticularGeneric(typeof(Listener<>));
```

Now we have the tools we need.

```
var listeners = from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                where type.AnyBaseType(IsListener)
                select type;
```

See how much easier the query is to read when you build up the tools you need one at a time?  What do we want to know? **If any base type is a listener**.  So how does the code read?  "where type any base type is listener" -- the code reads like a description of what it does.

Answer (score 6):

You can find out is any base type is a `Listener<>`, by recursively checking is target type `IsInheritedFrom` it:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static bool IsInheritedFrom(this Type type, Type Lookup)
    {
        var baseType = type.BaseType;
        if (baseType == null)
            return false;

        if (baseType.IsGenericType
                && baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == Lookup)
            return true;

        return baseType.IsInheritedFrom(Lookup);
    }
}

var lookup = typeof(Listener<>);
var listeners = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
    .Where(x => x.IsClass && !x.IsAbstract && x.IsInheritedFrom(lookup))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you your help. The above code work only if there is no third + extension. Meaning if I have `Foo : SendWelcomeEmail` this query wont return foo but would return `SendWelcomeEmail`