# how to check if a class implements and interface with a generic using c#?

Tags: c#

I have the following interface

```
public interface IHandleSuccess<T> where T : Event
{
    void Finished(T _event, Listener<T> listener);
}
```

And the following class

```
public abstract class Listener<T> where T : Event
{
    public abstract void Handle(T _event);
}
```

The following class which extends `Listener<T>` and implements `IHandleSuccess<T>`

```
public class SendConfirmationEmail : Listener<UserWasUpdated>, IHandleSuccess<UserWasUpdated>
{
    public override void Handle(UserWasUpdated _event)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Finished(UserWasUpdated _event, Listener<UserWasUpdated> listener)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Lastly, another listener that extends `Listener<T>` but does not implement `IHandleSuccess<T>`

```
public class ScheduleOriantation: Listener<UserWasUpdated>
{
    public override void Handle(UserWasUpdated _event)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

My `SendConfirmationEmail` gets class is registered into my `IoC` container when the application starts up.

I want to check if the resolved instance implements a contract. And if it does, I want to call the `Finished` method.

```
public void Announce<T>(T _event) where T : Event
{
    IEnumerable<Listener<T>> listeners = Container.ResolveAll<Listener<T>>()

    foreach (var listener in listeners)
    {
        try
        {
            listener.Handle(_event);

            if (listener is IHandleSuccess<> _listener)
            {
                _listener.Finished(_event, listener);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

However, the line `IHandleSuccess<>` is giving me an error

> Unexpected use of an unbound generic name

Since the generic argument will always extend the `Event` class, I also tried changing the code to the following

```
listener.Handle(_event);

if (listener is IHandleSuccess<Event> _listener)
{
    _listener.Finished(_event, listener);
}
```

But `_listener.Finished(_event, listener)` gives me the following error

> The second argument cannot convert from `Listener<T>` to `Listener<Event>`

How can I correctly fix this error?

Comment: I'm by no means a C# expert, but couldn't this be done with reflection? Just thinking out loud.

Comment: *is resolved using IoC container so the implementation will change*, this breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and is therefore bad design.

Comment: @Liam in my code `SendConfirmationEmail ` is resolved from IoC container so the implementation will not implement the interface where in my above example I am.

Comment: Yes, I deleted my original comment. The breaking of the LSP is still valid though. You should be concentrating on fixing this issue.

Comment: How is this fundamentally different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52886192/15498)?

Comment: So when you do use a IOC container what is the expected compiletime type or interface of cls? Show us in code form how you would get `cls` while using the container. If possible avoid `var` and use explicit type names in this updated example.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the previous question was trying to use reflection to identify class to register to my IoC container. In this question, I am trying to check if a listener implements an interface

Comment: *the previous question was trying to use reflection to identify class to register to my IoC container* that has caused this problem. I'd rethink this

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I edited my question to show more code to answer your question

Comment: @MikeA as I mentioned in my update to my comment, please replace all usages of `var` with the type var would have used, I need to know the exact return type of `GetListerners<T>()` It looks like a `List<Listener<T>>` but I don't want to make assumptions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already know what the generic type of `IHandleSuccess<>` will be, it will be `T` because you declared that you would be receiving `Listener<T>`'s from the request.

```
public void Announce<T>(T _event) where T : Event
{
    IEnumerable<Listener<T>> listeners = Container.ResolveAll<Listener<T>>()

    foreach (var listener in listeners)
    {
        try
        {
            listener.Handle(_event);

            if (listener is IHandleSuccess<T> _listener)
            {
                _listener.Finished(_event, listener);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a example if Announce was not generic

```
public void Announce(Foo _event)
{
    IEnumerable<Listener<Foo>> listeners = Container.ResolveAll<Listener<Foo>>()

    foreach (var listener in listeners)
    {
        try
        {
            listener.Handle(_event);

            if (listener is IHandleSuccess<Foo> _listener)
            {
                _listener.Finished(_event, listener);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't believe it was this simple

Comment: @MikeA please read through [bodin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52888635/80274) he makes some good points like passing `cls` in is unessesary, anywhere in the function you use `listener` in your `void Finished(T _event, Listener<T> listener);` function can be replaced with a simple `this.` call.

Answer (score 5):

This code doesn't work

```
var cls = new SendConfirmationEmail();

if (cls is IHandleSuccess<Event> _cls)
{
    _cls.Finished(_event, cls);
}
```

Because `cls` is of type `SendConfirmationEmail()` which implements `Listener<UserWasUpdated>` whereas `_cls` is casted as `IHandleSuccess<Event>`.
The function `_cls.Finished()` expect a parameter `listener` of type `Listener<Event>`, not `Listener<UserWasUpdated>`

What is the use of your function `Finished(UserWasUpdated _event, Listener<UserWasUpdated> listener)`?
Looking at the way you are using it, you could remove the parameterc`listener` and reference the current listener using `this`:

So the interface would look like this:

```
public interface IHandleSuccess<T> where T : Event
{
    void Finished(T _event);
}
```

And the implementation like this:

```
public class SendConfirmationEmail : Listener<UserWasUpdated>, IHandleSuccess<UserWasUpdated>
{
    public override void Handle(UserWasUpdated _event)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Finished(UserWasUpdated _event)
    {
        // Call whatever function on your object
        this.Cleanup()
    }
}
```

To answer you first question, this doesn't work because each use of the generic is a different type:

```
var cls = new SendConfirmationEmail();

if (cls is IHandleSuccess<> _cls)
{
    // _event and cls types can't be resolved at compilation time here:
    _cls.Finished(_event, cls);
}
```

If you want to be able to do this, you need to make you interface non generic.
If the `_event` object is known by your object `cls` beforehand, you can store it and use it in the `Finished()` call, like this:

Interface:

```
public interface IHandleSuccess
{
    void Finished();
}
```

And the implementation like this:

```
public class SendConfirmationEmail : Listener<UserWasUpdated>, IHandleSuccess
{
    private _Event = null;

    public override void Handle(UserWasUpdated _event)
    {
        // Store _event
        _Event = _event;
    }

    public void Finished()
    {
        // Call whatever function on your object
        this.Cleanup()

        // Call whatever is needed on _event
        _Event?.Cleanup();
    }
}
```

You can then do:

```
var cls = new SendConfirmationEmail();

if (cls is IHandleSuccess _cls)
{
    _cls.Finished();
}
```

Comment: At this point, do you agree that I should get rid of the IHandleSuccess and instead add a virtual method called `Finished` on my `Listener<T>` class?

Comment: If any implementations of `Listener<T>` needs to implement `Finished`  I would move it on `Listener<T>` yes.